# Fail during start Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using CentOS and I tried to run:
home/ps/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd test -netspeed full -no-audio -gpu off

I got this out:

```
Failed to open lib64EGL_translator Failed to init_egl_dispatch    emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES initialization failed! emulator: ERROR:    OpenGLES emulation library could not be initialized! emulator:    WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software    renderer. emulator: emulator window was out of view and was    recentered
```

and I don't know how fix this issue?